# Accessing raspberrypi.local from Nodemcu

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu

Currently I am trying to access a rest API from NodeMCU. The API is hosted on my local LAN on a Raspberry pi 3 b. The Raspberry pi is accessible on LAN using the raspberrypi.local domain address.
But the problem is I am unable to access the raspberrypi.local address form NodeMCU. 
It is unable to just resolve the address.
Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

In order to access the API, your NodeMCU needs to know the IP address your Pi has at this time. There are several ways to resolve `raspberrypi.local` to the actual IP. Assuming the NodeMCU got its IP assigned by your WiFi hotspot, it also received a DNS server IP. This is where the NodeMCU would ask first. However, if this DNS server is hosted by your internet provider, it obviously would not know what to respond when asked for your `raspberrypi.local`.

Another way, especially for `.local` domains, is [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS). NodeMCU has a [module](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/mdns/) to do that.

If you work with this a lot, consider running a local development network with your own DHCP/DNS combo. [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) is a good place to start. Lots of tutorials online. The Pi can host that for you.